# ReactJS drag and drop between multible tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i looked for this all day but couldn't figured out how to do it, appreciate a little help, i have two tables and what i want is drag and drop of multiple rows between those two tables closest thing which i got is [this](https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?path=/story/multi-drag--pattern) by enclosing tr into the draggable component but i feel it is workaround is there better way to do it i have the solution in jQuery but i don't want to mix 
jquery in my React application.

Comment: I havent tried this but there are some links you can try.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2nHLfiiKBA https://codepen.io/amishstripclub/pen/dpgjry  https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.com/?path=/story/tables--with-fixed-width-columns

Comment: Youtube link is HTML 5 drag and drop, codepen is header drag and drop in same table and react-beautiful-dnd is again row draggable in same table and i am struggling in two tables, single table is not an issue.

Comment: check this also.. https://react.rocks/tag/Drag_Drop?show=60

Comment: i think this is perfect example http://react-trello-board.web-pal.com/#

Comment: Hi @Vivek i checked all these but none of them is working with multiple rows for single row these will work same with trello example it is single drag and drop and am struggling with multiple rows, thanks.

Comment: ok but it cannot that tough. i have another link.. https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/patterns/multi-drag.md

Comment: also refer this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8IlGnKOb6E

Answer (score 0):

@techipank If you are not using infinite scroll, then you can use react-beautiful-dnd plugin to implement drag and drop between two links.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ql08j35j3q

Github link for package:
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/about/examples.md

Hope this will help you. Thanks